# Write a trigger on account when account is inserted if same name account already present in the system then old one deleted and new one is inserted

Tags: triggers, apex

Here is my code but not working-

```
trigger trgOnAccount on Account (before insert) {
    
    list<string>nameList=new list<string>();
    list<account>names=new list<account>();
  
    for(account ac:trigger.new){
     nameList.add(ac.name);   
    }
map<string,account>accMap=new map<string,account>([select name from account where name IN:nameList]);
    for(account ac:trigger.new){
       
        if(accMap.containsKey(ac.name)){
        names.add(accMap.Values()); 
       
        }
    } 
    delete names;
}
```